# Expression of Floor in Directory

Tags: word-choice

1. When writing addresses of commercial buildings, do people in the United Kingdom, Ireland, Australia and New Zealand like to write Level 3 (L3), while the United States and Canada like to write 3rd Floor or (Fl 3), if an company occupies the whole floor?
2. I see an [English floor directory in Japan](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/378795018638508457/). It uses 2F to express the 2nd floor, does is correct, compared to Fl 2? And I think floor directory in English speaking counties would often use the floor number only and neglect the word “floor” or “level”. Besides, How about the basement? B2F, mentioned in the picture, is rare in English speaking countries. But I wonder how to pronounce  -2, B2, LG2, “the second basement” or “Basement two” or “Lower Ground two” or anything else depends on countries? Also, how do you pronounce P2, “Parking Level 2” or “the second parking floor” or anything else?

Comment: Can confirm L3 is a common sight in Australia, Malaysia. You can see it in carparks.

Comment: @WeavingBird1917 I know people pronounce Level 0 as Ground Level, but can we say Level Zero? By the way, is Lower Level 2 (LL2) or Basement 2 (B2) more common in Australia?

Comment: @WeavingBird1917 As far as I know, the official language of Malaysia is Malay. So does Tingkat 3 (Malay of Level 3 by Google Translate) used with L3 (English) together on the floor guide/signage? I guess English cannot appear alone publicly in Malaysia, does it? “Can confirm”  sounds really Malaysian style.

Comment: "Ground floor" sounds most natural. "Ground level" works too. I haven't heard level 0 used before in colloquial speech. Never seen "LL2" used before. I regularly see "L3, B2, P2 (parking level 2)" used in buildings.

Comment: Also note you might see "C" on elevator buttons which stands for concierge. In large shopping centres in Malaysia, the signage is usually in English. I don't think remember whether they use put "Tingkat 3" and "L3" together, but I guess it's either one or the other.

Comment: *Concourse not concierge

Comment: In the UK the first floor is the one above the ground floor. In the USA the first floor is the one at ground level. But, in the UK at least, it's not common to use floor numbers in addresses.

Comment: @WeavingBird1917 Thank you for mentioning C for concourse. It reminds me L for lobby in some buildings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing an address on an envelope, you write whatever the person told you was the address. In the UK most flats don't use explicit floor numbers in the address

> Flat 73, 4 Park Road,
>   Town Name.
>   Postcode.

That *might* be a seventh floor flat, or it might not. The floor is not part of the address.

(for your address, you write whatever will get a letter to your home Your address is not "translated")

Lifts will use floor number usually just a number "7" Sometimes something else.  The letters and numbers used will usually tell you more about the company that installed the lift than about anything to do with the English language.

Floor guides are not common, if they exist they often just use "G", "1", "2", etc.  "LG" for "lower ground" is not uncommon. "Basement" is possible.  Shops with more than one level of basement that is used for selling are "as rare as hen's teeth" There is no really tradition of what to call such floor levels.

In speech we will say "the seventh floor" or sometimes "floor seven". As a learner that is enough. You hardly ever need to refer to floor numbers, and when you do you just say "seventh floor"

Comment: I agree with you. Do not “translate” the address when writing on the envelope. For example, write “3ème étage” rather than “Level 3” on a letter to Paris, France. However, what I want to talk about is how do we show floor information to English speaking tourists.

Comment: If the room number can be specified, that's fine. However, in some commercial places, the entire floor is usually leased to a company, so the floor will be displayed on the address. For example, Mitie Care & Custody Ltd is located at The Shared in London, United Kingdom. Level 12, 32 London Bridge St, London SE1 9SG.

Comment: I think floor guides are needed for departments stores, shopping centres and skyscrapers. Int the example I mentioned, B2 and B3 of Shibuya Hikarie Mall in Tokyo, Japan are food courts. In addition, the two-storey of basement at One World Trade Center in New York, United States is Westfield Shopping Center.

Comment: The floor guide seems to be very Japanese, A google search brings up Japanese Department store and very few examples from other countries.  Store guides for Harrods use "G", "1", "2" and for Liberty's uses  "Ground" "Floor 1" "Floor 2". Sure if Care & Custody have the whole floor then it will be "Level 12" or "Floor 12" or whatever, it will depend on how the floors are named in that particular building.

Comment: When you say "We", who are you? A department store? A Hotel?  And where are you?

Comment: Thank you. The expression of “floor guide” sounds Japanese, but store plan (in shopping centre) and building directory (in office building) are very common for multi-rise buildings in English-speaking countries, which are similar things. [UK: Harrods’s store guide](https://www.harrods.com/en-gb/store-guide), [UK: Selfridge store guide](https://www.selfridges.com/GB/en/features/info/stores/london/london-store-guide/), [US: Seattle Public Library directory](https://www.flickr.com/photos/thelostdutchman/1735067170).

Comment: I mean `store guide` not `store plan` in the comment above. Thanks for your suggestion and I revised the question.